# Unable to click anchor with image inside LI tag

Tags: watir, browser-automation

I have HTML like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Transitional//EN">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<HTML>
  <BODY class=" ext-border-box ext-ie ext-ie7 ext-windows" style="OVERFLOW: hidden">
    <DIV class=" x-viewport x-component x-border-layout-ct" id="x-auto-0" style="WIDTH: 1280px; HEIGHT: 862px" __eventBits="16384">
      <DIV class=" x-panel x-component x-border-panel" id="x-auto-9" style="BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; LEFT: 224px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 1054px; TOP: 35px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px">
        <DIV class="x-panel-bwrap"><DIV class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" style="WIDTH: 1054px; HEIGHT: 775px" __eventBits="16384">
          <DIV class=" x-tab-panel x-component" id="x-auto-17" hideFocus style="WIDTH: 1052px" __eventBits="6909">
            <DIV class="x-tab-panel-header x-unselectable" style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; WIDTH: 1052px" unselectable="on">
              <DIV class="x-tab-strip-wrap" style="WIDTH: 1052px" role="presentation">
                <UL class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top">
                  <LI class="x-tab-strip-closable  x-component x-tab-strip-active " id="x-auto-17__x-auto-180" hideFocus style="MozOutline: none" __eventBits="125" role="tab">
                    <A class="x-tab-strip-close" role="presentation"></A>
                  </LI>
                </UL>
              </DIV>
            </DIV>
          </DIV>
        </DIV>      
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am not able to click Object with `<A>` tag which has class attribute. I tried using three different ways

```
1. ie.link(:class,"x-tab-strip-close").click
2. ie.li(:class,"x-tab-strip-closable  x-component x-tab-strip-active ").link(:class,"x-tab-strip-close").click
3. ie.li(:xpath,"//li[@class='x-tab-strip-close']").click
```

All the three types resulted in element not found exception. Please let me know how do I click the element.

Comment: FYI there is no image in the link, the link is actually empty.  What you are seeing is most likely a 'background image' that is put there for that particular class by CSS

Answer (score 0):

Hey just try to do something like

```
 .link(:class, "x-tab-strip-closable x-component x-tab-strip-active").exist? == true
        begin
             browser.link(:class, "x-tab-strip-closable x-component x-tab-strip-active").click

          rescue => e
              rescueHandle(e)
          end
 else
     puts "FAILED! Could not find Class for Component"
         return false
  end
```

I think you will get to know more if some error are there.

Comment: 'browser' in the sense of browser object like 'ie'

Comment: thanks for the reply but .exist? is returing false, ie developer shows below html

Comment: I am not able to paste all ie developer tool output here. Can I attach a file in this forum? I can also send you the code to your email, if you want me to..

Answer (score 0):

This should work with the HTML you have provided:

```
browser.link(:class => "x-tab-strip-close").click
```

If you get "element not found" check if the link is in a frame. It could also be a timing issue, the link is not there when you are looking for it.

Comment: ie.link(:class, "x-tab-strip-close").exist? returns true but ie.link(:class, "x-tab-strip-close").visible? returns false. I am clearly able to see the element, I am not sure why .visible? should return false. The same activity was tried using QTP 9.5, using the same properties and element was successfully clicked.  Our application has no **Frames** but it uses lots of **Panels**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's part of some custom tab control that is using a lot of CSS and javascript running on the client.  I can find some postings in the Sencha "Ext JS" community forum that has similar class names.  Looking at some of their [samples](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/).

As with any page that has a lot of client side code doing CSS and other magic, you may need to wait a second or two after the page loads for the client side code to execute.  So that would be one of the first things I would try.

If not, I notice that a lot of the tab code is creating onmouseover events, and the contents of the DOM are changing on the fly when I mouseover tabs, so you may have to see if you can first fire an 'on-mouseover' event prior to trying to click on the item, potentially that could take it from a state where it is able to be clicked.

The other folks with similar tab names are ['EXT.NET'](http://www.ext.net/)  Again I can find stuff in their forums where these class names appear. I can also find examples of this (it's a button to close a tab) in their examples page for some of the tabs.  Similar advice regarding waiting, or trying onmouseover first, applies here as well.

If firing an event first doesn't work, and I'm right about the source of the controls, please see if you can find your control somewhere among their samples/examples and if so post the link, that will let folks here interact with a control of that style and gives us a better chance to figure out what makes it tick.

We also had a [similar request](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/eedff00e5fa39086?pli=1) from someone a few months back on the Watir google group, but the original poster ("Mahesh") never replied to potential answers so it is unknown if/how they resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to find the source of my control [Tab Scroller Menu Plugin](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/tabs/tab-scroller-menu.html). My requirement is to close the tab. Hope this helps

Comment: Can anyone please provide solution for this? As I have already posted I have found the source of my control([link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/tabs/tab-scroller-menu.html)), and there is no progress after that (I am still not able to close the tab control). If no solution is found soon then we may have to abort using WATIR in our project :(

Comment: Sorry, I was busy job searching and then getting started at a new position.  When I interact with the example of the code that you provided I notice that the little x icon to close the tab reacts and changes when I move the mouse over it.  That means it is doing something in relation to a mouseover event, and one of the things it may be doing is changing the visibility of the object.  Try firing an onmouseover event against that element first, waiting a second to let any client side code do it's thing, and then see if you can click the object.